# Repeat objects in list in R

Tags: r, list

I have two list files a and b:

```
a<-list(1,5,8,2,6,4,9,5)
b<-list(2,2,3,2,4,1,3,1)
```

I want every object in list a to repeat "matched objects of b" times, respectively.
The expected result is as follows:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 5 5

[[3]]
[1] 8 8 8

[[4]]
[1] 2 2

[[5]]
[1] 6 6 6 6

[[6]]
[1] 4

[[7]]
[1] 9 9 9

[[8]]
[1] 5
```

I use the code: `lapply(1:length(a), function(x) {rep(a[[x]],b[[x]])})`But I want to explore other ways. Thank you for help!

Comment: Do you mean `rep(a, b)` ?

Comment: I use the code as follows:  
 lapply(1:length(a), function(x) {rep(a[[x]],b[[x]])})

Comment: rep(a,b)can not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Map`!

```
Map(rep, a, b)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
mapply(function(x,y) rep(x,y), x = a, y = b)
[[1]]
[1] 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 5 5

[[3]]
[1] 8 8 8

[[4]]
[1] 2 2

[[5]]
[1] 6 6 6 6

[[6]]
[1] 4

[[7]]
[1] 9 9 9

[[8]]
[1] 5
```